# How can I record an audio from USB audio device using C++ with ffmpeg on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, ffmpeg

How can I record an audio from USB audio device using C++ with ffmpeg on Linux?
I have the following code. But I have no idea how to set the parameter of 'url' in the function of avformat_open_input.
Could assistance be provided by anybody? Much appreciated.

```
   27     av_register_all();
   28     avdevice_register_all();
   29
   30     //pAudioInputFmt =av_find_input_format("dshow");
   31     pAudioInputFmt =av_find_input_format("alsa");
   32     //assert(pAudioInputFmt != NULL);
   33     if (!(pAudioInputFmt != NULL))
   34     {
   35         printf("Error %s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
   36         char ch = cin.get();
   37         cout << "ch = "<< ch << endl;
   38         return (-1);
   39     }
   40
   41     // I have no idear how to set the second parameter on Linux.
   42     if (!(avformat_open_input(&pFmtCtx, "=Device)", pAudioInputFmt,NULL) == 0))
   43     {
   44         printf("Error %s %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
   45         system("pause");
   46         return (-1);
   47     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html) example of demuxing and decoding audio and video? By using only the audio part and filtering out what you don't need, you should be able to record audio.

Also, what do you get when executing

```
arecord -l
```

in the terminal? Given that you get something like

```
card x: USB audio
```

try to give "hw:x" as the input, where x is the number of the card given by the arecord -l command. In my case the USB microphone is card 1, so I give "hw:1" as the input to FFmpeg.